# How to do "from x.y.z import a" when "z" is a Python keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I ran into the unfortunate case where a particular file has the filename that is a keyword in Python. Is there some way to "bypass" this without renaming the file?

`libraries/import.py` has a function `my_function()`

```
from libraries.import import my_function
```

Gives:

```
E999 - SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and points at the "`.import`" part

I tried a few things:

```
from "libraries.import" import my_function
from libraries."import" import my_function
from libraries import import.my_function
from repr(libraries.import) import my_function
from `libraries.import` import my_function  # deprecated
import libraries.import.my_function
```

But they all have the same result: `SyntaxError`.

Can't find any tips in the Python manual either - but also no warnings about using reserved names :) Is this possible to do? How?

Comment: Its bad idea to name file with python reserve keyword, try `import importlib;my_function=importlib.import_module('libraries.import').my_function`

Answer (score 5):

You should really just reconsider renaming your submodules, not only do you need to resort to `importlib` in order to get it but, you'll also be confusing people.

To import you could just use `import_module` from `importlib`, that is:

```
from importlib import import_module 

m = import_module('libraries.import')
```

If you'd also want to bind the function to the global scope:

```
globals()['my_function'] = import_module('libraries.import').my_function
```

but you can see how ugly this is getting.

All alternatives you tried are either not allowed directly by the grammar (i.e `import "libraries.import"` or `import libraries."import"`) or they get rejected during the parsing phase were it is detected that one of [Pythons keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) is used.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's better to rename it.